# Why create a conditional checking if variable is -1 when iterating?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm sorry that this issue is hard to explain in a simple question but I have encountered it a couple times now and do not understand the functionality.

```
function checkArrays(batch){
  let newArray = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < batch.length; i++){
    let firstDigit = batch[i][0];
    if(newArray.indexOf(firstDigit) === -1){
      newArray.push(firstDigit);
    }
  }
  return new
}
```

**corrected variable from new to newArray**

This function takes in `batch`, a collection of arrays of single digits like [5,7,7,3,9,1,6,3]. The goal is to take the first digit of each array and add them to `new`, which is returned. My question is why is it necessary to check if `new.indexOf(firstDigit) === -1` in order to do this? What is significant about -1 and why would one want to iterate this way?
Thanks!

Comment: `new` is a reserved keyword and cannot be used as a variable name. `indexOf` returns -1 since there's no way to have an element at position -1 in an array.

Comment: Hint:  take a look at MDN's documentation for `indexof`:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: Because you tried to create a variable called `new`, and `new` is a reserved keyword, this is not a valid JavaScript program.  Can you please change the question and example to use a different name for that variable so we can move past that part of the issue?

Comment: The logic here is "if it's not in the array yet, then add it".  But this is sounding a lot like what a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) is for.

Comment: or use reduce https://playcode.io/706397

Comment: Thanks everyone, I just started coding in JS a few days ago and am generally inexperienced with coding so there's lots of unknown unknowns for me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
if(new.indexOf(firstDigit) === -1)
```

Basically means "if the element is not in the array", [because `indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

> ... returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

In most browsers you can also [use `includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) which is more semantically descriptive:

```
if(!new.includes(firstDigit))
```

---

As an aside... `new` is probably not a great name for a variable, since it's [an operator in the language itself](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new).  For this particular operation I'd go with something like `result` or `newArray` or something else a little more descriptive and not reserved.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This function will only return the first digit of arrays if they are unique, why is this?

Comment: @IanWiseman: Because that's what the function is written to do.  Any reasoning behind that is a question for whomever wrote it or decides that business functionality.

Comment: Sorry, my question was not about why it does this, but rather how does it do it. I see now that it's checking to see if a first digit is not in new and then pushing that given digit if the answer is true.